# How to read tsv into int np array in Collaboratory

Tags: python, numpy, integer, readfile

I have a text file consisting of

> 1 0 0 1
> 1 1 1 1
> 1 1 1 0
> 1 0 1 0
> 0 0 0 1

. I need it as integer array

```py
np.array([  
  [1, 0, 0, 1]  
  [1, 1, 1, 1]  
  [1, 1, 1, 0]   
  [1, 0, 1, 0]  
  [0, 0, 0, 1]  
])
```

in Google Collab.

If I do

```py
from google.colab import files
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

uploaded = files.upload()
data = pd.read_table('filename.txt')
np_arr = np.array(data)
```

, I get

```py
[  
  ['1 0 0 1']  
  ['1 1 1 1']  
  ['1 1 1 0']   
  ['1 0 1 0']  
  ['0 0 0 1']  
]
```

.

I couldn't use `dtype=int` to change those strings to integers.
Does annyone know how to do this?
Furthermore, I did it in the past without stating the actual filename, just using a dummy name and could therefore read new files without changing code (in Google Collab). Annyone aware of that possibility?

Comment: `np.loadtxt(path, dtype=int)`?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks Mark!